# Constrained NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, constraint

Consider `n` particles constrained on the surface of a unit sphere. $i^{th}$ particle experiences a force from every other $j^{th}$ of the form $$\vec{f_{ij}}=\frac{k \vec{r_{ij}}}{r_{ij}^m}$$

where $\vec{r_{ij}}$ points to $i$ from $j$. (say $k$=1, $m$=2).

To solve the equations one writes $\ddot{\vec{r_i}}=\vec{f_i}$ (RHS has been summed over $j$) then provides initial positions(say random) and velocities(say all zero). Feed these into NDSolve and we are good.

1. However what to do with the extra constraint equations? How to implement them in NDSolve?

In spherical coordinates, the constraints are simplest: $r_i=1$. So one converts everything to spherical coords. Now there is no extra constraint equation to implement via `Solve` but `NDSolve` is still annoyed

```
NDSolve::overdet: There are fewer dependent variables, {θ905[t],θ908[t],ϕ906[t],ϕ909[t]}, than equations, so the system is overdetermined.
```

since (for 2 particles) there are six equations of motion even after substituing the constraint but only 4 independents(the azimuths and zeniths).

2. How to overcome this?

**Code:**

```
symbs = StringPart["rθϕ", ;;];
eqnMaker[set_, iters_: 3] := 
  Nest[Thread /@ (Flatten[#]) &, set, iters];

symbs = StringPart["rθϕ", ;;];
n = 2;
vars = Table[Unique[#][t] & /@ symbs, {i, n}]
rs = CoordinateTransform["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", #] & /@ vars;
constraints = 
 Flatten[Distribute[#, List] & /@ 
   NestList[D[#, t] &, vars[[;; , 1]] -> 1, 2]]
F[r1_, r2_, m_: 2] := k (r1-r2) EuclideanDistance[r1, r2]^-m
F[r_] := Sum[F[r, R], {R, DeleteCases[vars, r]}]
eqns = eqnMaker[(D[#, {t, 2}] == F[#]) & /@ rs] /. constraints;

r0s = RandomPoint[Sphere[], n];
v0s = ConstantArray[0, {n, 3}];
ics = eqnMaker[{vars[[;; , 2 ;;]] == r0s[[;; , 2 ;;]], 
    D[vars[[;; , 2 ;;]], t] == v0s[[;; , 2 ;;]]}] /. t -> 0

vals = {k -> 1};
NDSolve[Join[eqns, ics] /. vals, vars, {t, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Sounds like you might want `Method -> {"Projection",...}`. If the numerical solution is accurate enough, you won't need it, but it will prevent drift off of the invariant equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it has been explained [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220869/stiffness-in-dae-particle-on-a-sphere/220973#220973) it could be better to use Euler-Lagrange equations for particles connected to sphere. There is a case `k=-1` corresponding to attraction and we consider this case below

```
k = -1; n = 4;

r[i_, t_] := {Cos[p[i][t]] Sin[q[i][t]], Sin[p[i][t]] Sin[q[i][t]], 
  Cos[q[i][t]]}
L = 1/2 Sum[ (q[i]'[t]^2 + Sin[q[i][t]]^2 p[i]'[t]^2), {i, n}] - 
   Sum[If[i == j, 0, 
     k/((r[i, t] - r[j, t]).(r[i, t] - r[j, t]))^(1/2)], {i, n}, {j, 
     n}];

eqQ[i_, t_] := D[D[L, q[i]'[t], t]] - D[L, q[i][t]]

eqP[i_, t_] := D[D[L, p[i]'[t], t]] - D[L, p[i][t]]

var = Flatten[Table[{q[i], p[i], q[i]', p[i]'}, {i, n}]];

ic = Flatten[
   Table[{q[i][0] == RandomReal[{Pi/2, Pi/2 + .1}], 
     p[i][0] == RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}], 
     q[i]'[0] == RandomReal[{-1, .1}], 
     p[i]'[0] == RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, {i, n}]];

sol = NDSolve[{Flatten[
     Table[{eqQ[i, t] == 0, eqP[i, t] == 0}, {i, n}]], ic}, 
   var, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Method -> Automatic];
```

Visualisation of trajectories on a sphere

```
Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[.3], Sphere[]}, Boxed -> False], 
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Evaluate[Table[r[i, t] /. sol[[1]], {i, n}]], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]]
```

[image: Figure 1]