# Stiffness in DAE: particle on a sphere

Tags: differential-equations, physics

While trying to apply ideas from the Stiffness related mathematica tutorials to my current problem , I keep getting errors like

```
NDSolve::nodae: The method NDSolve`StiffnessSwitching is not currently implemented to solve differential-algebraic equations. Use Method -> Automatic instead.
```

```
NDSolve::nodae: The method NDSolve`ExplicitRungeKutta is not currently implemented to solve differential-algebraic equations. Use Method -> Automatic instead.
```

but with automatic, the solution is stiff. How to alleviate this?

---

Consider a single particle constrained on the surface of a unit sphere. Its acted upon by a central force from an off center source:

$$
\vec{F}=k \, \frac{\vec{r}-\vec{r}_{source}}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}_{source}|^3}
$$

The problem exhibits stiffness. How to overcome this?

```
(*convenience*)
eqnMaker[set_, iters_: 3] := 
  Nest[Thread /@ (Flatten[#]) &, set, iters];
dropThird = Drop[#1, {3, Length[#1], 3}] &;
tang[vec_, R_] := vec - vec.Normalize[R] Normalize[R];

(*model*)
symbs = StringPart["xyz", ;;];
n = 1;
vars = Table[Unique[#][t] & /@ symbs, {i, n}];
rs = vars
rSource = Unique[#][t] & /@ symbs
F[r1_, r2_, m_: 3] := k (r1 - r2) EuclideanDistance[r1, r2]^-m
F[r_] := F[r, rSource]
constraints = Norm[#] == 1 & /@ vars
eqns = dropThird@eqnMaker[(D[#, {t, 2}] == F[#]) & /@ rs]

(*initial conditions and solving*)
r0s = {FromPolarCoordinates[{1, 1.35, 
    2.48}]};(*RandomPoint[Sphere[],n];*)
v0s = MapThread[tang[#1, #2] &, {0 RandomPoint[Sphere[], n], r0s}];
ics = eqnMaker[{rs == r0s, D[rs, t] == v0s}] /. t -> 0
vals = eqnMaker@{k -> 1, rSource -> 0.25 {1, 1, 1}}
sol = NDSolve[Join[eqns, ics, constraints] /. vals, vars, {t, 0, 100}];
s1 = vars /. First[sol];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220722/constrained-ndsolve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For dynamical problem on a sphere it could be better to use Lagrange equation directly, and not as projection of equation from cartesian coordinate to sphere. On a sphere we have coordinates `p, q` so that any vector is given by

```
r[i_, t_] := {Cos[p[i][t]] Sin[q[i][t]], Sin[p[i][t]] Sin[q[i][t]], 
  Cos[q[i][t]]}
```

Consequently the Lagrangian is defined as

```
L = 1/2 Sum[ (q[i]'[t]^2 + Sin[q[i][t]]^2 p[i]'[t]^2), {i, n}] - 
   Sum[If[i == j, 0, 
     k/((r[i, t] - r[j, t]).(r[i, t] - r[j, t]))^(1/2)], {i, n}, {j, 
     n}];
```

Equations of motion are

```
eqQ[i_, t_] := D[D[L, q[i]'[t], t]] - D[L, q[i][t]]

eqP[i_, t_] := D[D[L, p[i]'[t], t]] - D[L, p[i][t]]
```

Let define variables and initial conditions

```
var = Flatten[Table[{q[i], p[i], q[i]', p[i]'}, {i, n}]];

ic = Flatten[
   Table[{q[i][0] == RandomReal[{Pi/2, Pi/2 + .1}], 
     p[i][0] == RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}], 
     q[i]'[0] == RandomReal[{-1, .1}], 
     p[i]'[0] == RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, {i, n}]];
```

Now we ready to solve this system, for example put `k=1; n=2;`,then we have

```
sol = NDSolve[{Flatten[
    Table[{eqQ[i, t] == 0, eqP[i, t] == 0}, {i, n}]], ic}, 
  var, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Method -> Automatic]
```

Visualise `sol` on a sphere

```
Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[.3], Sphere[]}, Boxed -> False], 
 ParametricPlot3D[r[1, t] /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red], 
 ParametricPlot3D[r[2, t] /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> Green]]
```

[image]
Visualization in a case of arbitrary `n`

```
Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[.3], Sphere[]}
, Boxed -> False], 
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Evaluate[Table[r[i, t] /. sol[[1]], {i, n}]], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]]
```

For `n=4` we have
[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Thanks for solving the underlying system itself (here and elsewhere). However, why does the stiffness occur in the Cartesian or "projective" case? More simply, why couldn't I use the stiffness mitigation mechanisms?

Comment: @lineage It is very simple to understand, that cartesian projection of any trajectory shown in my Figure 1, 2 (with  `n=2,4` consequently) could not be unique. It also follows from equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$. Resolve it as $z=\pm \sqrt {1-x^2-y^2}$ we have two branches and it leads to stiffness and stop in every point `z=0`, but nothing happened in the spherical coordinates.